# Is index update atomic in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

**Setup**

- table with an integer column `number`
- `number` is not the primary key
- `number` may be NULL
- `number` has a unique index on it

**Scenario**

Potentially many concurrent workers, each performing this task:

1. perform a `max(number)` query, saving locally
2. updating a given row in the table with `number` set the the maximum incremented by one (was previously NULL for the given row)
3. catching any uniqueness constraint violations and requeueing the given row

Thousands of queued rows expected.

Essentially the idea is to extend a strict, gapless sequence on demand. Rows will exist in the table with a NULL `number` until they are sequenced. Once rows have a non-NULL `number` they are not deleted.

**Question**

The `max(number)` query is an index lookup. With many concurrent updates being attempted, what happens to the index updating? Does it:

- Block the `max(number)` queries while the index is updated? (thrashing index maintenance, and causing workers to wait)
- Indicate that the index is unsuitable to service the query, and fall back to a different plan involving scanning every row? (likely not thrashing index maintenance, but still causing workers to wait on slower queries)
- Return an outdated max result, similar to a non-threadsafe issue? (thrashing worker failure and requeuing)

Comment: **Every** DML (update, insert, delete) is atomic - that includes the changes to all indexes involved. Postgres will not use the index if it's not guaranteed to return correct information

Comment: search for isolation_level and MVCC

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe your statement is too categoric? E.g. GIST will give false matches, that would be filtered after reading index, so index is not guaranteed to return correct info. Unless I don't understand it of course :)